# transform() to add rows with dplyr()

Tags: r

I've got a data frame (df) with two variables, site and purchase.

I'd like to use dplyr() to group my data by site and purchase, and get the counts and percentages for the grouped data. I'd however also like the tibble to feature rows called ALLSITES, representing the data of all the sites grouped by purchase, so that I end up with a tibble looking similar to dfgoal.

The problem's that my current code doesn't get me the ALLSITES rows. I've tried adding a base R function into dplyr(), which doesn't work.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Starting point (df):

```
df <- data.frame(site=c("LON","MAD","PAR","MAD","PAR","MAD","PAR","MAD","PAR","LON","MAD","LON","MAD","MAD","MAD"),purchase=c("a1","a2","a1","a1","a1","a1","a1","a1","a1","a2","a1","a2","a1","a2","a1"))
```

Desired outcome:

```
dfgoal <- data.frame(site=c("LON","LON","MAD","MAD","PAR","ALLSITES","ALLSITES"),purchase=c("a1","a2","a1","a2","a1","a1","a2"),bin=c(1,2,6,2,4,11,4),pin_per=c(33.33333,66.66667,75.00000,25.00000,100.00000,73.33333,26.66666))
```

Current code:

```
  library(dplyr)
  df  %>% 
  group_by(site, purchase) %>% 
  summarize(bin = sum(purchase==purchase)) %>%
  group_by(site) %>%
  mutate(bin_per = (bin/sum(bin)*100))

  df  %>% 
  rbind(df, transform(df, site = "ALLSITES") %>%
  group_by(site, purchase) %>% 
  summarize(bin = sum(purchase==purchase)) %>%
  group_by(site) %>%
  mutate(bin_per = (bin/sum(bin)*100))
```

Comment: Suppose if `df1` is the first output then `df1 %>% ungroup() %>% group_by(site = 'ALLSITES', purchase) %>% summarise(bin = sum(bin)) %>% ungroup %>% mutate(bin_per = 100*(bin/sum(bin))) %>% bind_rows(df1, .)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can start from the first output code block, after grouping by 'site' with a created string of 'ALLSITES' and 'purchase' get the `sum` of 'bin' and later 'bin_per', then with `bind_rows` row bind the two datasets

```
df1 %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  group_by(site = 'ALLSITES', purchase) %>%
  summarise(bin = sum(bin)) %>% 
  ungroup %>% 
  mutate(bin_per = 100*(bin/sum(bin))) %>% 
  bind_rows(df1, .)
```